# How to check request body is null in azure api management policies expression?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I try to check request body like this.

```xml
<set-variable name="isBody" value="@{
    bool rtn_result = false;
    if (context.Request.Body == null)
    {
        rtn_result = true;
    }
    return rtn_result;
}" />
```

but 'rtn_result' return **false** always

I followed the document and they told me

> "context.Request Body: IMessageBody or null if request doesn't have a body."

What I mistake?

What is the right thing?
What should I do?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition does not make sense.
It returns `true` if there's **no** body.

Please change it to:

```cs
if (context.Request.Body != null)
{
  rtn_result = true;
}
```

Complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="isBody" value="@{
            bool rtn_result = false;
            if (context.Request.Body != null)
            {
                rtn_result = true;
            }
            return rtn_result;
        }" />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{   
                var response = new JObject();
                response["hasBody"] = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("isBody");
                return response.ToString();
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Result with body:
[image]

Result without body:
[image]